# Does $PATH need subdirectories

Tags: macos, bash, path

Given a $PATH like:

```
/Users/myname/bin:
/usr/local/Cellar:
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p362/bin:
... and so forth
```

do I really need the ruby location or is /usr/local/Cellar sufficient to find ruby?

Comment: Yes, your shell won't recursively search for binaries in those folders

Answer (score 5):

The entries are independent of each other, and only count the direct contents.  Try it.

```
> mkdir ~/bin
> mkdir ~/bin/test
> cp /bin/echo ~/bin/test/echotest
> export PATH=$PATH:~/bin
> echotest Hello, world
-bash: echotest: command not found
> rm -rf ~/bin/test
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, when you type a plain command name and it isn't a function or alias, then the shell logically takes the name and tries each directory in PATH in turn.  In pseudo-code:

```
name=command_to_execute
for path in ${names in PATH}
    exec $path/$name "${arguments[@]}"
report "failed to find command $name"
```

If the `exec` succeeds, there's nothing more to do.  If the `exec` fails, it tries the next directory.

Note that path search never applies to names containing a slash.  And the shell only searches in exactly the directories listed in PATH (but empty entries are interpreted as references to `.`, the current directory).  It won't look in sub-directories of its own volition; you would have to list the sub-directories in PATH.